# Phaser - On key release?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Instead of detecting when a key is down, how do I detect if a key is released?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use [`onUpCallback`](http://phaser.io/docs/2.4.6/Phaser.Keyboard.html#onUpCallback). For example, in your `create` function add something like the following:

```
game.input.keyboard.onUpCallback = function (e) {
    // These can be checked against Phaser.Keyboard.UP, for example.
    console.log(e.keyCode);
};
```

I suppose you could also store whether the key is down in your `update` function, and then check on each iteration whether it's up, if you wanted to keep track of the amount of time the key were pressed down.

I'm not sure what sort of performance issues you would run into though, so I would probably start with `onUpCallback`.

Comment: What do you do if this gives you the error, "Cannot set property 'onUpCallback' of undefined"?

Comment: That suggests that `keyboard` isn't defined. I'd need to see more code to troubleshoot beyond that.

Comment: Turns out I was trying to add the keyboard events on regular images and sprites when really it can only be added to the game object.

Answer (score 1):

Set a flag when the key is pressed. In the update loop check if the flag is set but the key is no longer down:

```
//... somewhere
var downFlag = false;

//... in update
if(yourkey.isDown){
   downFlag = true;
}else{
   if(downFlag){
      downFlag = false;
      //do something
   }
}
```

..but start with what James says